# How can I manipulate a numpy array without nested loops?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a MxN numpy array denoted arr, I wish to index over all elements and adjust the values like so

```
for m in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for n in range(arr.shape[1]):
        arr[m, n] += x**2 * np.cos(m) * np.sin(n)
```

Where x is a random float.

Is there a way to broadcast this over the entire array without needing to loop? Thus, speeding up the run time.

Comment: You could do an "inline" for something like this if you were using a function `[return x+i for x in lst]` But dont know how else you would access elements without a for loop.

Comment: You could but does it makes sense? np.cos(2*pi*m) * np.sin(2*pi*n) is equal to 0 as it is just multiples of 2*pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just adding zeros, because `sin(2*pi*k) = 0` for integer `k`.

However, if you want to vectorize this, the function `np.meshgrid` could help you.
Check the following example, where I removed the `2 pi` in the trigonometric functions to add something unequal zero.

```py
x = 2
arr = np.arange(12, dtype=float).reshape(4, 3)
n, m = np.meshgrid(np.arange(arr.shape[1]), np.arange(arr.shape[0]), sparse=True)
arr += x**2 * np.cos(m) * np.sin(n)
arr
```

Edit: use the sparse argument to reduce memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested generators of two-dimensional arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from random import random

x = random()
n, m = 10,20
arr = [[x**2 * np.cos(2*np.pi*j) * np.sin(2*np.pi*i) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [156]: arr = np.ones((2, 3))
```

Replace the `range` with `arange`:

```
In [157]: m, n = np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1])
```

And change the first array to (2,1) shape.  A (2,1) array broadcasts with a (3,) to produce a (2,3) result.

```
In [158]: A = 0.23**2 * np.cos(m[:, None]) * np.sin(n)
In [159]: A
Out[159]: 
array([[0.        , 0.04451382, 0.04810183],
       [0.        , 0.02405092, 0.02598953]])
In [160]: arr + A
Out[160]: 
array([[1.        , 1.04451382, 1.04810183],
       [1.        , 1.02405092, 1.02598953]])
```

The meshgrid suggested in the accepted answer does the same thing:

```
In [161]: np.meshgrid(m, n, sparse=True, indexing="ij")
Out[161]: 
[array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2]])]
```

This broadcasting may be clearer with:

```
In [162]: m, n
Out[162]: (array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]))
In [163]: m[:, None] * 10 + n
Out[163]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```